# C++ Child struct with different variable names than parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I made a 3d vector class like this

```
struct Vector3D {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector3D() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }

    Vector3D(float x1,float y1,float z1=0) {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        z = z1;
    }

    //member functions for operator overloading, dot product, etc.
};
```

But now I want to make a child class specific to Euler angles. So far I have

```
struct Euler3D : Vector3D {
      float roll;
      float pitch;
      float yaw;
};
```

How do I make the class so that roll pitch and yaw reference the same data as x, y and z? I think it involves `union` or something.
I want to be able to achieve something like this:

```
Euler3D a = {1, 2, 3};
cout << a.x << endl; // prints 1
a.x = 1.5;
cout << a.roll << endl; //prints 1.5
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why have `Euler3D` inherent from `Vector3D` at all if they are completely unrelated? If you _really need_ to have them share memory, you could create a separate union with members of `Euler3D` and `Vector3D`.

Comment: The trick is to turn it into a class and make the x,y,z protected. Everything else will follow. I.e. setter, getter; then two different pairs of setter,getter.

Comment: @Brian I want to be able to use the member functions from vector3d in Euler3d

Comment: @Yunnosch this is running on a microcontroller so I want to minimize overhead by using public variables instead of a lot of getters and setters

Comment: would ```#define roll x``` be easiest?

Comment: @Plasmabot No, because then any time you use the `roll` identifier it will be replaced with `x`. i.e. `int x = myVector.x; int roll = myEuler.roll; // Error because you've defined int x twice!`

Comment: @Plasmabot Why do you think using public variables minimizes overhead? It doesn't.

Comment: Your best bet is almost certainly to make `Euler3D` a separate class with converting constructors and operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make the class so that roll pitch and yaw reference the same data as x, y and z?

You cannot.

Since you want to refer to an object, you could use reference instead, but that breaks copying - you can fix copy constructor by using user defined one. Furthermore (just like your duplication) this introduces unnecessary memory overhead.

---

What you can do is write a function that returns reference to the member. like this:

```
struct Euler3D : Vector3D {
      float& roll() { return x; }
```

But this is not ideal either because you probably need at least a second set of overloads for const, so plenty of boilerplate.

> I think it involves union or something.

You can use an union to have aliased members, but then you cannot have the inheritance. This is allowed:

```
struct Euler3D {
    union { float x, roll;  };
    union { float y, pitch; };
    union { float z, yaw;   };
};
```

Which you can use exactly as in your snippet.

Comment: Can I just do #define roll x because this is only for readability purposes

Comment: @Plasmabot You don't want to do that.

Comment: Usually, you can only read from the last `union` member to have been set. Is there an exception for `union` members of the same type? Edit : type*

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Accessing union member of same type as the active one is allowed, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make the class so that roll pitch and yaw reference the same
>   data as x, y and z?

The clue is in the word "reference" - you can make the members of the derived class **references** to the corresponding members in the base.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this will also require the class to have a copy constructor:

```cpp
struct Euler3D : Vector3D {
    float& roll = Vector3D::x;   // You don't actually need the "Vector3D::" ...
    float& pitch = Vector3D::y;  // ... qualifiers here, but using them adds ...
    float& yaw = Vector3D::z;    // ... clarity for more complex cases.
    Euler3D() { }                // Should have def. ctor as we define the copy!
    Euler3D(const Euler3D& rhs) : Vector3D(rhs) { }
};
```

Here's a short piece of code to illustrate how this could work:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Euler3D* e3d = new Euler3D;
    e3d->roll = 1.1f;
    e3d->pitch = 2.2f;
    e3d->yaw = 3.3f;
    Vector3D* v3d = dynamic_cast<Vector3D*>(e3d);
    std::cout << v3d->x << " " << v3d->y << " " << v3d->z << std::endl;
    Euler3D e3d2 = *e3d;
    std::cout << e3d2.roll << " " << e3d2.pitch << " " << e3d2.yaw << std::endl;    // Copied from RHS
    e3d2.roll = 4.4f; e3d2.pitch = 5.5f; e3d2.yaw = 6.6f;
    std::cout << e3d2.roll << " " << e3d2.pitch << " " << e3d2.yaw << std::endl;    // Changed
    std::cout << v3d->x << " " << v3d->y << " " << v3d->z << std::endl;             // Not changed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you copy `Euler3D`?

Comment: Edit: oh, assignment isn't even broken. Yeah, fixing constructor works.

Comment: Also, his goal was to minimize overhead for the microcontroller. This adds _very significant overhead_